# Require authentication for (almost) every request using ServiceStack

Tags: authentication, servicestack

I am building an ERP using ServiceStack and have authentication wired in and working.  However, I'd like to require authentication on basically every single route, DTO, or static page - except the Login page and supporting resources (CSS, images).

Is there a simple, centralized way of doing this?  I could apply `[Authenticate]` to every DTO/route, but it'd be easy to miss one.

How can I require authentication for all requests, save some?  I suspect a [global request filter](http://docs.servicestack.net/request-and-response-filters#global-request-filters) of some form, but I'm not sure how to start that.

Comment: http://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization

Answer (score 1):

Right, the easiest way is to use a [Global Request Filter](http://docs.servicestack.net/request-and-response-filters#global-request-filters):

```
GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, dto) => {
    if (!req.IsAuthenticated())
    {
        res.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        res.EndRequest();
    }
});
```

This will ensure all Service Requests are authenticated, to also validate non Service Requests handled by ServiceStack are authenticated you can use a `PreRequestFilters` instead:

```
PreRequestFilters.Add((req, res) => {
    if (!req.IsAuthenticated())
    {
        res.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        res.EndRequest();
    }
});
```

Comment: Quick experimentation shows that static content isn't picked up by the global filter.  How would I (selectively) filter that content?

Comment: @jklemmack you can use a `PreRequestFilters`, see my updated answer.

Comment: The global request filter should probably allow Authenticate requests.  Then again, the most secure system is one no one can access :)

Answer (score 1):

@mythz's solution is the most correct, but in my situation I had some specific additional criteria I didn't originally ask.  Namely, I wanted to permit `Authenticate` requests, and to redirect users to the login page.  I am using a custom Authentication provider [ServiceStack.Authentication.Azure](https://github.com/ticky74/ServiceStack.Authentication.Azure), so I ended up with a 303 Redirect instead of 403 Fail (or, more appropriately, 401 Unauthorized) to make it work with my OAuth-style provider.

```
this.GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, requestDto) =>
{
    if (!req.IsAuthenticated() && !(requestDto is Authenticate))
    {
        res.RedirectToUrl("/auth/aadgraph?redirect=" + req.RawUrl.UrlEncode());
        res.EndRequest();
    }
});
```